# Greeting issue apigee configuration in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apigee

I want to configure apigee with GCP but getting error The project is not entitled for an Apigee organization like this
And i have tried to connect with sales team but not get response from them

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use developer tools in the browser and if error was like 40X Forbidden.If so, it is possible that you don't have the right permissions on the project where you want to set up Apigee. I think this (roles/apigee.admin) is the permission you need.